# Unable to destroy activity

Tags: android, flutter, location, crashlytics

This error appeared to me in firebase crashlytics.

The title of exception is `FlutterLocationService.java`

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.eightworx.excrm/com.eightworx.excrm.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method i.o.c.e.d, parameter activity
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5240)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5269)
   at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:181)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:102)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2205)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7829)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:512)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:986)
```

Caused By

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method i.o.c.e.d, parameter activity
   at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService.a(FlutterLocationService.java:2)
   at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.c(LocationPlugin.java:51)
   at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.detachActivity(LocationPlugin.java)
   at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.access$000(LocationPlugin.java)
   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.b(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:54)
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onDetach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:58)
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onDetach(FlutterFragment.java:7)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDetach(Fragment.java:3)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1184)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.l(FragmentManagerImpl.java:93)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a(FragmentManagerImpl.java:42)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.d(FragmentManagerImpl.java:4)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.h(FragmentManagerImpl.java:7)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:4)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:5)
   at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8262)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1342)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5225)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5269)
   at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:181)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:102)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2205)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7829)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:512)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:986)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend posting some code relating to what is actually causing the error so that we can help you with a solution. Have a look at [how to ask a great question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Comment: this exception happened in firebase crashlytics and can not determine where is the exception dose?!

Comment: i guess that something related to permission of location service, i think it happened because the location permission requested twice first time when run the app and second when hot restart the app, Thanks for you reply.